# Does A-Frame 1.0 support marker-less Augmented reality on IOS and android?

Tags: aframe, webxr

I came across an [A-frame blog](https://aframe.io/blog/aframe-v1.0.0/) on WebXR support in the AR mode. but w3c showing [disclaimer](https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr-ar-module-1/) which says API is in development and unstable. I am trying to understand the mystery, How A-Frame support marker-less AR today since w3c says "Immersive Web Working Group has been working on the WebXR API for AR to introduce a more open AR platform on the web"

Comment: You might wanna read https://aframe.io/blog/webxr-ar-module/

Comment: @DiegoMarcos thanks for the response. but [there](https://aframe.io/blog/webxr-ar-module/) is nothing mentioned about iOS support. I will try the code example.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos, I watched the SFHTML5 conference videos on youtube. it was really inspiring. 

Do you think we can build for android and ios progressively? we can support for ios as the API becomes mature(1.0). and what is the best frontend stack for AR and VR applications today?